# Is freeing an allocated pointer with a null value necessary?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I wonder, if I have the following code:

```
var = (double *)calloc(vars_ptr->amount, sizeof(double));
if (var == NULL) {
     printf("ERROR: Problem in memory allocation");
     exit(1);
}
```

Is it possible there will be a memory leak? I mean exiting without freeing, since it indicates the memory allocation process didn't take place.

Comment: If you don't have an allocation, how could you free?

Comment: Don’t forget that error messages should be written to `stderr` and should end with a beeline.  There’s no leak because no memory was allocated.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Error messages should indeed go straight to the user, but the way to get that beeline is with a new line.

Comment: I should make a beeline for the newline character, @EricPostpischil.  I put it down to under-caffeinated use of an iPhone equipped with a fully functional spell mangler.

Answer (score 2):

If no memory was allocated, you don't have to free anything.

That said, `free(NULL)` isn't harmful. It just doesn't do anything.

That said, there is no point in freeing memory just before you're exiting anyway. That's not a memory leak; a leak would be not freeing memory and keeping running.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, this

```
var = (double*)calloc(vars_ptr->amount, sizeof(double));
if (var == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: Problem in memory allocation");
    /* @TODO proper error handling i.e use error no &  stderr */
    exit(1);
}
```

*doesn't causes memory leak*, as if call to `calloc()` fails i.e memory allocation was failed i.e you don't have to call `free()`.

From [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

> **7.20.3.2**  **The `free` function**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> The `free` function  causes  the  space  pointed  to  by ptr to  be 
>   deallocated,  that  is,  made available for further allocation.
>   *If **ptr** is a **null** pointer, **no action occurs***.

Answer (score 1):

If the returned pointer is equal to NULL then this means that the memory was not allocated.

From the description of the function `calloc` (C11 Standard)

> 3 The calloc function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to
>   the allocated space.

You may call `free` for a null-pointer though this does not have an effect.

On the other hand, you may require a memory of zero size. In this case if the returned pointer is not equal to NULL you have to call `free` to free the allocated memory.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int *p = calloc( 0, sizeof( int ) );

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        printf( "p = %p\n", ( void * )p );
    }

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Using an inline compiler its output

```
p = 0x55efd9c81260
```

That is though the required size of memory is equal to 0 nevertheless the system allocated memory that needs to be freed.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `malloc` or `calloc`, and the call returns NULL, that means that nothing has been allocated, so nothing has to be freed, and there's no memory leak.

The case you have to worry about concerns `realloc`:

```
newp = realloc(oldp, newsize);
```

If `realloc` returns NULL, then `oldp` still points to the old memory (if any).  If you were to write

```
p = realloc(p, newsize);
```

this would be a memory leak waiting to happen, the first time `realloc` failed.  (That is, `p` would contain `NULL`, and the old, still-valid pointer would be lost.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing:

- If you are asking whether you should call `free(var)` before exiting the program, it is obviously not necessary since `var == NULL` when this memory allocation failed. There is nothing to free in `var`. Calling `free(var)` is allowed, but will do nothing.
- If you are asking whether you should free other memory blocks allocated by your program before exiting it on a fatal error for this particular allocation attempt, it is not necessary either because all memory allocated by the OS to the program is released upon exit.
- Other system resources such as open files, locks, semaphores... should be released automatically as well but you might still leave the environment in an inconsistent state by exiting the program abruptly like that. For example you might leave some files with inconsistent contents, undeleted temporary files, pending network transactions, inconsistent database updates...

Answer (score 0):

the code you uploaded allocates memory, not freeing it.

according to the info at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/ and 
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc) - calloc returns NULL if the function failed to allocate memory from the OS. thus, it's a good practice to check the pointer after the function call, in order to avoi.

I'd say that if the function fails, either you're trying to allocate way too much memory, or that a memory leak already has occured, so I wouldn't worry about exiting the code after failure - it's probably for the best.